# notification sound not working when video is recording

Tags: android, audio, notifications

In my app, the user have an option to record video. While the user is recording video, if the app triggers a local notification, the notification sound is missing.

But apps like Hangouts, System alarm etc. are able to trigger a notification with sound.

Tried setting notification priority to maximum, requesting audio focus but no luck.

```
notificationBuilder.setPriority(2);
notificationBuilder.setSound(soundUri, AudioManager.AUDIOFOCUS_GAIN_TRANSIENT);
```

Is there a way to trigger a notification with sound, when camera recording is on ? Or is this the default behaviour ? Workarounds ?

Environment: Nexus 7, Android 6.0.1

PS: Whatsapp is able to generate notifications with sound on One Plus 2(Android 6.0.1) when video recording is on.

Comment: Probably they just play that sound with `MediaPlayer` ? Did you try it?

Comment: Nope didn't try it. Did not want to go through the media player route. Will try and update.